# Take subset from DataFrame based on multiple str patterns

Tags: python, pandas, concatenation, subset

I have a pandas DataFrame `df`. From `df` I want to take a subset if either `flsa_w_gk` or `flsa_w_fcm` is contained in the `df['model']`.

For only one string, I would do it as follows:

```
mask = df['model'].str.contains('FLSA_W_fcm', case=False, na=False)
subset = df[mask]
```

The approach below works, but seems too lengthy:

```
mask1 = df['model'].str.contains('FLSA_W_fcm', case=False, na=False)
subset1 = df[mask1]

mask2 = df['model'].str.contains('FLSA_W_gk', case=False, na=False)
subset2 = df[mask2]

frames = [subset1, subset2]
subset = pd.concat(frames)
```

Is there a way to do this using fewer lines of code?

Comment: You can use ```|```   (or) in string contains. ```str.contains('FLSA_W_fcm|FLSA_W_gk')```

Answer (score 1):

Use `|` for join strings for regex `or`, so finally is only one mask:

```
subset = df[df['model'].str.contains('FLSA_W_fcm|FLSA_W_gk', case=False, na=False)]
```